# Switch to panel - Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, switch-statement

After a click, a mini banner (or a container drawer) opens, which I should click on it, but I can't interact with it.

I was trying the "driver.switchTo" command but since there is no Iframe, I don't know how to do it.

the body is this:

`<a class="option"> Go </a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had issues with this in the past, and largely I couldn't figure out what to do either.  If you can just leave your computer alone during the process you can always try to use pyautogui to kind of cheat your way through it.